# React hook value not updating in async function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to validate my fields that uses hooks with this code:

```
const validate = async () => {        
        if (!new ValidateFields().checkIfValidSnn(snn.value))
            setSnn({ ...snn, error: "Invalid snn" })
        if (!new ValidateFields().checkIfValidPhone(phone.value))
            setPhone({ ...phone, error: "Invalid phone number" })
        if (!new ValidateFields().checkIfValidEmail(email.value))
            setEmail({ ...email, error: "Invalid Email" })
        if (country.value.length <= 0)
            setCountry({ ...country, error: "Please select a country" })
  
    return [snn, phone, email, country].every(x => x.error == "" && x.value != "")
}

const submit = () => {
    validate()
        .then(success => {
            if (success)
                console.log("SUCCESS!")
            else
                console.log("Failed")
        })
}
```

But the problem is that all changes is not being changed by the time validate ruturns a value. How can i get the correct value without running the function again?

Answer (score 1):

`setState` call async, so you cannot be sure of the current value. You can store the validation state in a local variable. And you don’t need to mark a function `async` if it doesn’t use `await`.

```
const validate = () => {
    let isValid = true;

    if (!new ValidateFields().checkIfValidSnn(snn.value)) {
        setSnn({ ...snn, error: 'Invalid snn' });
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!new ValidateFields().checkIfValidPhone(phone.value)) {
        setPhone({ ...phone, error: 'Invalid phone number' });
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!new ValidateFields().checkIfValidEmail(email.value)) {
        setEmail({ ...email, error: 'Invalid Email' });
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (country.value.length <= 0) {
        setCountry({ ...country, error: 'Please select a country' });
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
};

const submit = () => {
    if (validate()) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!")
    } else {
        console.log("Failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but I would prefer to not have a extra check with the boolean flag.But i guess this will work for now :)